# Why i cannot change variable value inside onCreate when i am using methodto change it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why i cannot change variable nama , nomor_induk value inside onCreate when i am using method requestData to change it ?
i already declare   private String nama,no_induk; outside onCreate Method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mPrefs = ((BimbPA) getApplication()).getPrefs();
    isLogin = mPrefs.getUserisSignIn();
    if (isLogin == true){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.form_mhs_menu);
        Intent i=getIntent();
        mApiService = UtilsApi.getAPIService();
        requestData();



        TV_nama.setText(nama);
        TV_no_induk.setText(no_induk);
        Log.d("nama", nama);
        Log.d("no induk", no_induk);


    ~

}
```

this is my method to change my variable

```
public void requestData(){
    Log.d("user id ", String.valueOf(mPrefs.getUserID()));
    mApiService.loggedinuserrequest(String.valueOf(mPrefs.getUserID()))
            .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonRESULTS = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            if (jsonRESULTS.getString("error").equals("false")){
                                // Jika login berhasil maka data nama yang ada di response API
                                // akan diparsing ke activity selanjutnya.
                                nama = jsonRESULTS.getJSONObject("user").getString("nama");
                                no_induk = jsonRESULTS.getJSONObject("user").getString("nomor_induk");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("debug", "onFailure: ERROR > " + t.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any place in `onCreate()` where you attempt to modify the variables you listed.

Comment: under mApiService = UtilsApi.getAPIService(); in oncreate
i declare method requestdata() which is to change my nama and no_induk variable from database
and then i want use that variable (nama and no_induk) to change my textview @azurefrog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requestData()` method sets up an asynchronous network call and then returns. The async call itself executes on another thread and completes later, firing one of the methods in the `Callback`.

You need to update your UI only later when the async call has completed, such as in `onResponse()`.